# How to know the word under the right click in Word

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have `VBA` for `Word` that adds a button to the context menu of the right click which launches my application (which works).

I need the word clicked on to pass it as argument. I saw that I couldn't use `Selection` because right click doesn't select the word, it gives me the letter after the cursor.

With what I've read, I could possibly look at the position of the cursor, then look at both sides to where the word begins and finishes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to work

```
Selection.Words(1).Text
```

**Edit**

A little more robust to account for ends of sentences.

```
Sub FindWord()

    Dim rWord As Range

    If Selection.Words(1).Text = vbCr Then 'end of sentence
        'get last word of sentence
        Set rWord = Selection.Words(1).Previous(wdWord)
    Else
        'get selected word
        Set rWord = Selection.Words(1)
    End If

    'There has to be a better way than this
    If rWord.Text = "." Or rWord.Text = "?" Then
        Set rWord = rWord.Previous(wdWord)
    End If

    Debug.Print rWord.Text

End Sub
```

Comment: Nice one I must say :-) The only scenario where my code and your code fails is if the cursor is at the end of the word and there is no space after the word. For example "This is a" If the last word in a sentence is "a" and there is no space after "a" and if the cursor is after "a" then it doesn't work...

Comment: Amazing! thank you so much! Even simpler and shorter that I could imagine! I feel kinda stupid to have missed that but at least you solved my problem. Thanks again!

Comment: @SiddharthRout I agree but it's find for me :P

Answer (score 1):

Here is the most simple way to check for the word under the cursor.

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim pos As Long

    '~~> if the cursor is at the end of the word
    Selection.MoveEnd Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1

    Do While Len(Trim(Selection.Text)) = 0
        '~~> Move one character behind so that the cursor is
        '~~> at the begining or in the middle
        Selection.MoveEnd Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=-1
    Loop

    '~~> Expand to get the word
    Selection.Expand Unit:=wdWord

    '~~> Display the word
    Debug.Print Selection.Text
End Sub
```